# mongodb random sample strange behavior

Tags: python, mongodb, random

I am using:

```
mongodb server 3.47
windows 10 64-bit
python 3.62 64-bit
pymongo 3.50
```

There are two record in "k" collection in "dict" database:

```
{"text": "xdcdcdcd", "sent": "false"}
{"text": "vvrvrrrv", "sent": "true"}
```

I want to choose a random record which has "sent" equals false:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.dict
k = db.k
item = list(k.aggregate([{"$sample": {"size": 1}}, {"$match": {"sent": False}}]))
```

The variable item should be "[{"_id":".....", "text": "xdcdcdcd", "sent": "false"}]", but I tried several times, sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it returns [].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mongo's aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) is a pipeline action. It means that it will apply your aggregate list one by one.

In your example, it does two steps(you have two elements in your lists):

```
1. {"$sample": {"size": 1}}
2. {"$match": {"sent": False}}
```

The first step you get only one data(`size=1`), It's either `{"text": "xdcdcdcd", "sent": "false"}` or `{"text": "vvrvrrrv", "sent": "true"}`.

And then in step two you apply `"$match"`, there is 50% you will get `[]`(when you get `{"text": "vvrvrrrv", "sent": "true"}` in first step).

So if you set `{"size": 1}` you will always get what you expected.

But actually the `{"$sample": {"size": 1}}` is useless, just delete it.